# How to distribute torrent files?

Tags: cloud, bittorrent

I am doing some distributed work with RackSpace cloud servers and I am using bittorrent to distribute my files. It works surprisingly well. However, distributing the torrent files themselves are not so nice. How would you go around doing that? Right now I just scp the torrent files to the servers, and of course I could write a script that copies it to `sqrt(n)` servers instructing each to again copy to `sqrt(n)` but that's a pita to work it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not knowing what exactly your problem is, I can recommend `pscp` from [parallel-ssh](http://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/) as a tool to upload small files to multiple servers.

You prepare a list of servers to upload to and let it know what to take locally and where to put it remotely. For example:

```
$ pscp -h list-of-servers file.torrent /tmp/
[1] 02:11:22 [SUCCESS] 10.0.0.21
[2] 02:11:22 [SUCCESS] 10.0.0.20
[3] 02:11:22 [SUCCESS] 10.0.0.45
[4] 02:11:22 [SUCCESS] 10.0.0.19
[5] 02:11:22 [SUCCESS] 10.0.0.2
[6] 02:11:22 [SUCCESS] 10.0.0.5
[7] 02:11:25 [FAILURE] 10.0.0.3 Exited with error code 1
```

Comment: There's also http://code.google.com/p/pdsh/

Answer (score 15):

Given they're very small files typically couldn't you just have a 'dropbox' using HTTP with a cron'ed script doing a curl/wget with wildcard?

Comment: This is the method I would use, no need to push a file out to each server and maintain a server list, have them periodically check for new .torrent file

Comment: you could also use Puppet to do this

Answer (score 8):

You could have the torrent clients  check an rss feed for new torrent files or switch to magnet links instead of torrent files.

Comment: RSS may not be an option if he/she is using a basic command line torrent client.

Comment: He could you [Flexget](http://flexget.com/) with rtorrent without gui

Comment: Yep, flexget and rtorrent would work well for this

Comment: +1 "switch to magnet links instead of torrent files."

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into [murder](https://github.com/lg/murder)

> Murder is a method of using Bittorrent to distribute files to a large amount of servers within a production environment. This allows
>   for scaleable and fast deploys in environments of hundreds to tens of
>   thousands of servers where centralized distribution systems wouldn't
>   otherwise function

.

Murder was/is developed by the folks at [twitter](http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/07/murder-fast-datacenter-code-deploys.html), and they're using it daily to distribute files.

Comment: project is no longer maintained.